# Ignoring design time constraints set in IOS

Tags: ios, constraints

Lets say I have set a constraint for a label during design time and does not have any reference to those constraints to modify later. Lets assume that I set x and y position constraints during design time. When this control is being rendered, what if I set a different value for x and y by using frame.origin.x and frame.origin.y. Does this override the constraint I set in design time or constraint will win over this?

Comment: No, the constraints will override any value you set to the frame

Comment: Yes, but only if `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints == false`. Otherwise setting a view's frame _will_ have an effect (see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55719732/2062785) below).

Comment: How about just trying it out? 

Comment: Bad idea to try an mix-and-match constraints and frames. Add `IBOutlet`s for your constraints, and modify the `.constant` property at run-time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really get what your understanding of a "design time constraint" is but here's the general mechanism how constraints work (and the behavior is all about your view's [autoresizing mask setting](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622572-translatesautoresizingmaskintoco)):

- `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints == false`
  ⇒ Setting your views frame does not have any effect as it will be overridden by your constraints in the next layout pass.
- `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints == true`
  ⇒ Setting your view's frame adds several constraints behind the scenes the enforce that the view has the frame's size and position. However, it's important to know that in this case, you should not add any other constraints to the view as they will conflict with the "frame constraints".

If you want to understand the details, check out [▶️ this talk](https://youtu.be/xjArhdrqAn8?t=1892).

I also published an article on Medium not to long ago with [very granular explanations on the autoresizing mask](https://medium.com/@PhiJay/the-auto-layout-comprehendium-%EF%B8%8F-6d7e2105bf70) that is probably very relevant to your question (scroll to section *Deactivating Auto Layout*).

---

*Note:*
There is a way to have constraints only affect your layout at design time. You simply select the constraint in Interface Builder and check the *Placeholder* checkbox.

[image: Placeholder Checkbox]

But from what I can tell it's not what you are talking about.

Comment: Yes. I am not talking about the remove at build time constraints. I mean to say during design I set some constraints for X and Y and when the control is rendering if I change X and Y, would that affect the control position or the pre set constraints override it.

Comment: Dude, you gotta be more precise. You cannot set "constraints for X and Y". You can only set leading constraints, for example (or trailing, top, bottom, ...), that are relative to another view. I guess what you mean by X and Y is `frame.origin.x` and `frame.origin.y`, am I correct? And the constraints you have is a leading and a top constraint with the view's superview? If that is so, then setting the view's frame at runtime won't have any effect, unless the view's `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` property is set to `true`.

Comment: You should take the time to watch the explanations in the talk referenced above and read the article. That should answer all your questions (in case my answer above did not.)

Comment: I will take a look at the video and yes I meant leading and trailing.